# Using "having" on join clause of Spring JPA specification

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jpql, specifications

I have a repository of `User`s; each `User` has a OneToMany relationship with a collection of `Post`s.
How can I filter (and page) the repository of users by the number of posts they have using JPA specifications?

My initial attempt looked as such:

```
public static Specification<User> receiptNumberGreaterThanOrEqualTo(int numberToFilterBy) {
    return (users, query, cb) -> greaterThanOrEqualTo(cb.count(users.get("posts")), Long.valueOf(numberToFilterBy));
}
```

This however caused an error to the effect of:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')>=9 limit 100'
```

This is because the @OneToMany join expects a `HAVING` clause to be used rather than `WHERE`, i.e. `select * from users outer left join posts on users.id = posts.id having(count(posts) > someNumber) where user.id = "some-id"`
vs
`select * from users outer left join posts on users.id = posts.id where user.id = "something" and count(posts) > someNumber;`

I can generate a query with the having keyword by creating a join between user and posts, and then doing as follows: 
`query.having(cb.greaterThanOrEqualTo(cb.count(joinOfPosts), Long.valueOf(numberToFilterBy)))`, but the type of this is `CriteriaQuery`, and I'm unsure how to turn this into a Specification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this by using the size() method on the criteriaBuilder,

ie.

```
(users, query, criteriaBuilder) -> criteriaBuilder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(criteriaBuilder.size(users.get("posts")), numberToFilterBy);
```